# What is the effect of still feeling a movement after doing this movement during the day called and what causes it?

Tags: sleep, exercise

After a long day of sailing or a boat, or sitting in a car, or heavy sporting, et cetera, one might feel, while lying perfectly still in bed (or resting in another way), as if the body is still performing the motion of the waves (or car, or sport).

How is this effect called, and what causes it?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! This is interesting as I experienced this after a long ferry trip on choppy seas. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Think ["sea legs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusions_of_self-motion) (kinda the opposite of what you're describing, but absolutely related.) If you still have questions, please edit what you've learned and why it still confuses you into your question. Thanks. (Oh, and it goes by various names, sometimes based on the cause or severity.)

Comment: OMG hello @anongoodnurse!  Happy to see you poking back in!  And great response as usual.